# Does one get back his neshama in the exact form when resurrected?

Tags: tefilla, soul, resurrection-of-the-dead

I'm viewing the phrasing in the paragraph  Elokai Neshamah:

> ואתה עתיד לטלה
>   ממני ולהחזירה בי לעתיד לבא

My loose translation:

In the future, you will take it from me and return it to me in the (further) future.

Does this imply that when we are resurrected, we get our soul back in the exact state that it was at the point that it was taken from us (I assume this means, when we die)?

Comment: Does a neshama change states?

Comment: @Daniel You may be able to enlighten me on this, perhaps. The *Nevi'im* frequently mention getting a new *lev*. I'm uncertain of the difference of *lev* and *neshama* esp. when viewing that concept.

Comment: An answer assumed you are asking about reincarnation (gilgul). I assumed upon reading the question that you were asking about resurrection (techiyas hameisim). Could you clarify?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you would think of _lev_ and _neshama_ as the same thing. At least on the surface they seem like entirely different concepts. I'm no expert in these things but I always imagined the neshama as the pure piece of Hashem that's in each of us, so to speak. I don't see why the state of the neshama would ever change. What different states were you thinking of?

Answer (score 2):

I am not entirely sure what we mean when discussing the "state" of a neshama, but the Ramchal in several places discusses the concept that when the neshama comes back to the body it will be at a much higher level. His reasoning is as follows:

The neshama is by its nature lofty and spiritual, and if left to its own nature, would immediately refine and purify the physicality of the body. This would obviously eliminate the whole purpose of putting the body and the neshama together, as it would eliminate the entire context for the challenge of choosing spirituality. Therefore, Hashem artificially limited the neshama (or, more accurately, commanded the neshama to limit itself) such that it would not do this. However, even after that, upon the performance of a mitzvah, the spiritual "energy" (for lack of a better word) that the neshama would gain would immediately cause the same imbalance, and the neshama would refine the body. Therefore, the spiritual "energy" (still haven't come up with a better word) was put on hold. The neshama will gain this spiritual growth from the mitzvos that it does in the "World of Souls," which is where the neshamos go after a person dies. When the neshama returns to the body, it is with this heightened spiritual energy that it is able to refine the body and bring it up to the level where they can be partners in receiving the eternal reward.

A representative excerpt from Derech Hashem (1:3:12):

> יב. ואולם מלבד היות עולם הנשמות מקום לנשמות לשבת בו כל זמן היותן מצפות לגוף, כמו שכתבנו, הנה עוד תועלת גדול נמצא בו לנשמות עצמן ואחריהן לגוף, למה שיצטרך אחר כך בזמן התחיה. וזה, כי אחר שהיתה הגזירה על האדם שלא יגיע לשלימות אלא אחרי המות, אף על פי שכבר נראה לו מצד מעשיו עודנו חי, כי זולת זה לא היה מגיע לו מעולם, שהרי אין זמן קניית השלימות אלא בעולם הזה טרם המוות, וכמו שנתבאר; עוד נמשך מן הגזירה הזאת, שהנשמה כל זמן היותה בגוף בעולם הזה שהרע דבוק בו, שאי אפשר שיפרד ממנו לגמרי, תהיה גם היא חשוכה ועמומה. ואף על פי שעל ידי המעשים הטובים שהאדם עושה קונה היא בעצמה שלימות יקר, לא יוכל הדבר להיגלות, ולא תוכל להזדהר בזוהר שהיה ראוי לה להזדהר כפי היקר ההוא שהיא משגת באמת, אלא הכל נשאר כבוש בעצמותה עד הזמן שינתן להיגלות. ואולם אין העכבה מצידה כלל, כי אם מצד הגוף, כמו שנתבאר. והוא עצמו מפסיד בזה, שלא יקבל כל אותו הזמן הזיכוך שהיה ראוי שיקבל, כמו שנתבאר. אמנם גם היא מפסדת, שהיא כבושה בעצמה ואינה יכולה לפשט זהריה. ועוד, שאינה פועלת הפעולה הראויה לה, שהיא זיכוך הגוף. ואילו היתה פועלת אותה, היתה משתלמת בזה שלימות גדול מצד מהות הפעולה עצמה, שהרי פעולת שלימות היא היות מיטיב ומשלים זולתו. ועוד, שזאת היא הפעולה הנאותה לה לפי מבעה וחוקה, שלכך נוצרה; וכל נברא משתלם כשפועל מה שחקק לו בוראו יתברך שיפעל, וחסר משלימות כל זמן שלא יפעלהו. ואמנם בצאת הנשמה מהגוף ולכתה אל עולם הנשמות, הנה שם מתפשטת ומזדהרת בזהריה כפי מה שראוי לה על פי מעשיה, ובמה שהיא משגת שם כל זמן היותה שם, מתחזקת ממה שנתחלשה בגוף, ומזדמנת יותר למה שראוי שתעשה בזמן התחיה, עד שכשתשוב בגוף בזמן הראוי, תוכל לפעול בו הפעולה הנאותה לה, דהיינו הזיכוך שזכרנו